# Why can I not read a UTF-16 file longer than 4094 characters?

Tags: c++, linux, utf-16, wstring, wifstream

**Some information:**

- I've only tried this on Linux
- I've tried both with GCC (7.2.0) and Clang (3.8.1)
- It requires C++11 or higher to my understanding

**What happens when I run it**

I get the expected string "abcd" repeated until it hits the position of 4094 characters. After that all it outputs is this sign "?" until the end of the file.

**What do I think about this?**

I think this is not the expected behavior and that it must be a bug somewhere.

**Code you can test with:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

void createTestFile() {
  std::ofstream file ("utf16le.txt", std::ofstream::binary);
  if (file.is_open()) {
    uint16_t bom = 0xFEFF; // UTF-16 little endian BOM
    uint64_t abcd = 0x0064006300620061; // UTF-16 "abcd" string
    file.write((char*)&bom,2);
    for (size_t i=0; i<2000; i++) {
      file.write((char*)&abcd,8);
    }
    file.close();
  }
}

int main() {
  //createTestFile(); // uncomment to make the test file

  std::wifstream file;
  std::wstring line;

  file.open("utf16le.txt");
  file.imbue(std::locale(file.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));
  if (file.is_open()) {
    while (getline(file,line)) {
      std::wcout << line << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The example worked fine for me. I get a file with 2000 times "abcd" and it's properly displayed. Tried it with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: How are you verifying the file?  Perhaps your viewer has a bug?

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am happy that it works on Windows correctly without any changes, I want to stay cross plattform compatible if I can. Then the bug must have something to do with Linux I would guess. Maybe even something silly like the terminal I use...?

Comment: What program are you viewing the file in?

Comment: Reproduced with gcc 7.1.1 After setting a breakpoint with a debugger, and examining the contents of the read string, all signs are pointing to a libstdc++ bug. The read string is 8000 wide characters, as expected. But starting at `line[4094]`, the endianness is rudely reversed. You should open a gcc bug, and attach the output of the debugger, showing what's in `line[4093]` and `line[4094]`

Comment: @MichaelDorgan In my code above I output the contents into stdout and reads it from there using my terminal. That's where it starts displaying ? signs after 4094 bytes are written to it. The file is ok and verified, but my code to read the file seems to not function properly on my system.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you very much for your analysis! I've never submitted any bug reports before and I am pretty much new to this whole open source scene. I might try to open a gcc bug, but I've never even used a C++ debugger before.

Comment: Well, now this is a perfect learning opportunity. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. Your first project is to reproduce my results. This will get mangled by stackoverflow.com due to lack of linebreaks in comments, but: `(gdb) p line[4093]
$19 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<wchar_t> >::value_type &) @0x628244: 98 L'b'
(gdb) p line[4094]
$20 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<wchar_t> >::value_type &) @0x628248: 25344 L'挀'` - the C++ library obviously botched reading this string.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik maybe you could write your answer as an answer instead of comment, then OP can link to this thread in the bug report

Comment: Does a binary dump of the file confirm that the contents are correct? @SamVarshavchik that question is for you too.

Comment: Yup, the binary dump shows that it's correct. Verified by dumping it with `od -v`.

Comment: `<codecvt>` is [deprecated](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html). It was badly specified and the implementation never got around of implementing it semi-correctly. Don't use it.

Comment: @n.m. It's marked as deprecated in C++17 but with no std alternatives. What do you suggest I use instead?

Comment: Did someone tried libcxx ?

Comment: My first choice would be avoiding utf16 entirely. Failing that, use a platform or third-party unicode conversion library like iconv.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a library bug to me. Stepping through the sample program as compiled by gcc 7.1.1 using `gdb`:

```
(gdb) n
28      while (getline(file,line)) {
(gdb) n
29        std::wcout << line << std::endl;
(gdb) p line.size()
$1 = 8000
```

8000 characters read, as expected. But then:

```
(gdb) p line[4092]
$18 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<wchar_t> >::value_type &) @0x628240: 97 L'a'
(gdb) p line[4093]
$19 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<wchar_t> >::value_type &) @0x628244: 98 L'b'
(gdb) p line[4094]
$20 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<wchar_t> >::value_type &) @0x628248: 25344 L'挀'
(gdb) p line[4095]
$21 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<wchar_t> >::value_type &) @0x62824c: 25600 L'搀'
(gdb) p line[4096]
$22 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<wchar_t> >::value_type &) @0x628250: 24832 L'愀'
```

`line[4092]` and `line[4093]` look ok. But then, I see `line[4094]`, `line[4095]`, and `line[4096]`, containing `6300`, `6400` and `6500`, instead of `0063`, `0064`, and `0065`.

So, this is getting messed up starting with character 4094, and not 4096, actually. I dumped the binary UTF-16 file, and it looks correct to me. The BOM marker is followed by consistent endian-ness for the entire contents of the file.

The only thing that's puzzling is why both clang and gcc are supposedly affected, but a quick Google search indicates that clang also uses gcc's libstdc++, at least up until recently. So, this looks like a libstdc++ bug to me.